# MySQL - Query optimalization - Using where; Using temporary; SELECT Query taking longer than 10 seconds

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

I have a query that is taking a lot of time to complete. It calculates a rank based on row_number() for a certain user. (I know there is also rank(), but I prefer row_number() in my calculations)
The query takes up to 10 seconds to complete. There are 4.5million records in the table.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  AttackerGuid, 
            ROW_NUMBER()   OVER w AS 'row_number',
            `Marks`
    FROM 
     (
        SELECT attackerguid, count(*) as 'Marks'
        FROM playermarkskill
        WHERE type = 'D' and ServerID = 2
        group by AttackerGuid
     ) p
     WINDOW w as (ORDER BY `Marks` DESC)
) p2
WHERE p2.AttackerGuid = '80235184'
```

This returns:
[image: MySQL return]

With the following execution plan:
[image: MySQL execution plan]

Comment: Not a MySQL expert, but it looks like MySQL isn't using an index of AttackerGuid for the playermarkskill table. Does it get any faster if you have an index over (ServerID, AttackerGuid)?

Comment: You could also try: instead of selecting the row number of every row, select the number of rows which are before the one you want.

Comment: There is no `ORDER BY` in the `OVER`, so, are you getting random numbers?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and what the output should be.